# Can the BrickStore part database be updated?

Tags: software, inventory

Is there a way to update BrickStore database with new element numbers, sets, and pictures of the elements? How would you do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found this on [Eurobricks from 2014](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/99118-brickstore-database/):

> I recommend to try BrickStock instead of BrickStore. Brickstore is old and is no longer supported and updated. BrickStock is a fork (using the source of BrickStore) of brickstore.

I use Brickset.com which is very up-to-date and suits the needs of me and my sons.